# Switch mysql to mysql2 gem cause all unicode to mess up

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, mysql2

Before my app was on Heroku and used mysql gem.
When I migrate that data into my own mysql database, and switch to mysql2 gem, my uncode character is viewed in their raw utf8 form.

In the other hand, if I update unicode data into database using mysql2 gem, then switch back to mysql gem, I get back question mark if I query for unicode character.

From my observation, mysql gem produces identical output compare to mysql client utility (on my Ubuntu) while mysql2 does not.

Is there a way to tell mysql2 gem to read data and encode using the same way mysql client does? (and thus in the same way mysql gem does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to dump the data into a .sql file, use a unicode converter to convert that .sql file to proper encoding and then dump it back to the server.

Comment: Which converter you've been using?

Comment: I'm use a unikey converter, which may only be helpful if you use Vietnamese.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problems when migrating data to and from Heroku, you should be able to force encoding in database.yml with

```
encoding: utf8
```

Point to make also is that Heroku uses PostgreSQL by default, even if you've included mysql gem.

Comment: This setting is already there in my database.yml. My issues also posted on issues list of mysql2 gem: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/149. Don't know why but right now both mysql and mysql2 gem produce me the utf8 (raw format) of the unicode text 8-x

Comment: I think that the `encoding: utf8` (lowercase) format is the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I also got a lot of problems with this, but made a dirty solution. Thing is, in Rails 2, the 'mysql' gem seems to accept a latin1 encoded string from the mysql database (default) as utf 8.

mysql2 does not do this anymore. Loading from activerecord in rails2 with the mysql gem, shows the correct output, but in rails3, the mysql gem does not work anymore. Therefor, go to a console in rails2, and use the following snippet. I use a copy of the database, in case you want to go back.

```
def update_instance_from_backup(current_instance)
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql",
      :host     => "localhost",
      :username => "...",
      :password => "...",
      :database => "database_backup"
    )
    attributes = current_instance.class.find(current_instance.id).attributes
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql2",
      :host     => "localhost",
      :username => "...",
      :password => "...",
      :database => "database",
      :encoding => "utf8"
    )
  rescue
  else
    current_instance.update_attributes attributes
    puts "#{current_instance.class.name} #{current_instance.id} (dd. #{current_instance.updated_at}) updated"
  end
end
```

Now, you can call update_instance_from_backup(instance) on any activerecord instance.

```
foo = Foo.find(3)
update_instance_from_backup(foo)
```

Will let you update your instance data. You can of course do a loop yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a migration to fix this, as with all things, your mileage may vary.

```
class FixUnicodeCrap < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    r = ActiveRecord::Base.run_sql(<<sql
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA = database()
       and DATA_TYPE in ('varchar','text')
       and CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'latin1'    
sql
)
    r.each do |row|
      target_type = 'BLOB'
      if row[5] == 'varchar'
        target_type = "VARBINARY(#{row[4]})"
      end
      null = row[3] == 'YES' ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL"
      if (row[0] != 'page_views') # if you need to skip any dbs, change this
        execute "ALTER TABLE #{row[0]} MODIFY #{row[1]} #{target_type};"
        execute "ALTER TABLE #{row[0]} MODIFY #{row[1]} #{row[2]} CHARACTER SET utf8 #{null};"
      end
    end
  end

  def down
  end
end


module EasySql
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(Extensions)
  end

  module Extensions
    def run_sql(sql, *args) 
      connection.execute(
        sanitize_sql_array([sql] + args)
      )
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, EasySql
```